# Sending cookies with third party HTTP requests

Tags: html, http, cookies

I am using a forms/landing page maker called Hubspot and I am inserting custom images that are not hosted on Hubspot. This means that whenever the page is being loaded, the browser makes a request to my custom image URL but since it is third party and not on the same domain, the cookies that I have set are not being sent with this request. I am wondering if there is a way I can send cookies with the third party request, even though they are first party.

I have tried looking online for a solution but found nothing.

Thanks in advance!